# How to maintain push ups training

Tags: push-ups

I trained for several months in order to achieve my goal of a hundred push ups in a row. To do so, I slowly increased the number of push ups every time I trained. I did not do the training with push ups in a row, it was just the goal.

Now that I can do it, I'd like to maintain my level. How should I do it? Will doing 100 push-ups frequently be sufficient, or should I divide my training again ?

Just to be clear, I don't want to increase my number of push ups (I don't want too large muscles), just to be able to do 100 push ups in the future.

Comment: Just keep at it, do 100 pushups. Your body has no reason to lose strength if you keep doing what you can already do. The only thing you might lose is a bit of muscle mass, since the movements become repetitive, and since that is not a problem to you thats ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just wanted to add that doing much more than 100 push-ups will likely not make your muscle much bigger. That's not how muscles grow bigger as far as I understand it...

Hi rep push-ups based on a gradual progression of increase in rep is like an endurance run. Once you build the base muscle, you will be maintaining the endurance, and your muscle will not grow notably bigger (unless you start varying the type of push-ups and add weight to the push-up (ex: have someone sit on your back while pushing-up, etc)).